# How can I sort by first column textually and then by the second numerically with 'sort'?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sorting

I'm trying to sort the following file:

```
a 2
b 1
a 10
```

I need to get:

```
a 2
a 10
b 1
```

I know about the -kPOS[opts] option, and try to use it:

```
sort -k1 -k2n file
```

but this command gives me only:

```
a 10
a 2
b 1
```

So it sorts by the first column, but no by the second. Running just `sort -k2n file` sorts by the second column.

```
b 1
a 2
a 10
```

How could I sort it by two columns?

### Edit:

sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to terminate the primary key, otherwise, sort uses all the fields starting from the given one:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2n
```

Answer (score 7):

It is almost correct. Try this:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have `GNU sort` sort then you can do a version sort:

```
$ sort -V file
a 2
a 10
b 1
```

Option:

```
-V, --version-sort          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

The nice thing about version sorting is it will work regardless of columns:

```
$ cat file
a2
b1
a10

$ sort -V file
a2
a10
b1
```

Comment: I use sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93. It doesn't have the `-V` option.

Comment: I have `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.15`. Too bad, check `--help` to see if version sort is available under a different option.

Comment: In `--help` I don't see any version option except `--version`. Anyway, what is the magic? What does the "version sort" mean?

Comment: I've added a little more info to my answer.